# Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class

Tags: android, layout, preferencefragment

I get this error when inflating the layout for a `PreferenceFragment`, but I can't get the reason, because I can't find any list in the layout.

Here is the (trivial) layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.myPath.SettingsFragment">
</FrameLayout>
```

Here is the code that raise the Runtime exception:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    ...
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
    }
}
```

Here is the full exception stack:

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myPath.SettingsActivity}:
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' 
   that is not a ListView class
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2658)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
      Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class
    at android.preference.PreferenceFragment.ensureList(PreferenceFragment.java:397)
    at android.preference.PreferenceFragment.getListView(PreferenceFragment.java:363)
    at android.preference.PreferenceFragment.bindPreferences(PreferenceFragment.java:345)
    at android.preference.PreferenceFragment.onActivityCreated(PreferenceFragment.java:185)
    at android.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2122)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:833)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6257)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2621)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: @CommonsWare , posted. Maybe the code / layout for the parent activity can help too?

Comment: Why are you using `PreferenceFragment` here in the first place? The point behind `PreferenceFragment` is to show a list of preferences, and you seem to be actively attempting to prevent it from showing a list of preferences, by replacing the `ListView` with a `FrameLayout`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, so should I replace FrameLayout with ListView in my Layout? This seems fair... But even using `android:id="@+id/list"` in it, causes the same error. Related question: is it really necessary to create a layout for a PreferenceFragment or there are other ways?

Comment: "so should I replace FrameLayout with ListView in my Layout?" -- most likely, you should eliminate the layout and the `onCreateView()` method. `PreferenceFragment` already has a layout. "is it really necessary to create a layout for a PreferenceFragment" -- no. In fact, I have never seen anyone create a layout for a `PreferenceFragment`.

Answer (score 0):

as the logcat shows u need to have a listview with id as android.R.id.list for it to be working,

btw why are adding layout to preferenceFragment ,i think u need Fragment here. Preference Fragment are used for showing list of options so it need a listview with that id for it to be working

Comment: I am setting up a list of option, that's why I am using PreferenceFragment.

Comment: why are supplying layout to it, remove the onCreateView code to solve the issue

Comment: Yes, that obviously solves the issue, but I can't see the preferences, although this should be another question..

Comment: why are not using listview then

Comment: in your layout make a listview with mentioned id and you are good to go with that too

Comment: Same error with ListView in place of FrameLayout, and adding `android:id="@+id/list"` didn't help either. Is it really necessary to use this layout? Are there other ways to format my PreferenceFragment?

Comment: use @android:id/list for listview id